# My code doesn't produce any output -- Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two columns of data 
([sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4TAu.png)) and I want to calculate total users for each week day.

For instance, I'd want my output like this (dict/list anything will do):

Monday: 25,
Tuesday: 30,
Wednesday:45,
Thursday: 50,
Friday:24,
Saturday:22,
Sunday:21

Here's my attempt:

```
def rider_ship (filename):
    with open('./data/Washington-2016-Summary.csv','r') as f_in:

        Sdict = []
        Cdict = []
        reader = csv.DictReader(f_in)
        for row in reader:
            if row['user_type']=="Subscriber": 
                if row['day_of_week'] in Sdict:
                    Sdict[row['day_of_week']]+=1
                else: 
                    Sdict [row['day_of_week']] = row['day_of_week']
            else:
                if row ['day_of_week'] in Cdict:
                    Cdict[row['day_of_week']] +=1
                else: 
                     Cdict[row['day_of_week']] = row['day_of_week']

        return Sdict, Cdict

        print (Sdict)
        print (Cdict)

t= rider_ship ('./data/Washington-2016-Summary.csv')
print (t)
```

TypeError::list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Sdict = {}
Cdict = {} to start with

Comment: Okay. Done, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

How about using pandas?

Let's first create a file-like object with io library:

```
import io
s = u"""day_of_week,user_type
Monday,subscriber
Tuesday,customer
Tuesday,subscriber
Tuesday,subscriber"""
file = io.StringIO(s)
```

Now to the actual code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(file) # "path/to/file.csv"

Sdict = df[df["user_type"] == "subscriber"]["day_of_week"].value_counts().to_dict()
Cdict = df[df["user_type"] == "customer"]["day_of_week"].value_counts().to_dict()
```

Now we have:

> Sdict = {'Tuesday': 2, 'Monday': 1}
>
> Cdict = {'Tuesday': 1}

Comment: Looks great. Thanks Anton.

Comment: @shreyaagarwal Great! Consider marking the question answered.